# Call to function gets stuck, but monitor seems to get freed, how?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have the following design in a project

- Multiple crawlers
- a list `ImageList` for found images (`Observable`); this gets updated by **threaded** processes (thus parallel)
- two observers which listen to the list (`Downloader` and `ImagesWindow`); caveat: these can be notified multiple times, because the list gets updated by threads

I always wanted to get only the newest entries from `ImageList` so I implemented it with a **counter**:

```
public class ImageList extends Observable {
    private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, Image> images = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Image>();
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /* There is some more code within here, but its not that important
       important is that stuff gets added to the list and the list shall
       inform all listeners about the change

       The observers then check which is the newest ID in the list (often +1
       but I guess I will reduce the inform frequency somehow)
       and call (in synchronized method):

       int lastIndex = list.getCurrentLastIndex();
       getImagesFromTo(myNextValue, lastIndex);
       myNextValue = lastIndex + 1;
    */

    public synchronized void addToFinished(Image job) throws InterruptedException {
        int currentCounter = counter.incrementAndGet();

        images.put(currentCounter, job);

        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }

    public synchronized int getCurrentLastIndex() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public ArrayList<Image> getImagesFromTo(int starting, int ending) {
        ArrayList<Image> newImages = new ArrayList<Image>();

        Image image;
        for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++) {
            image = images.get(i);
            if (image != null) {
                newImages.add(image);
            }
        }

        return newImages;
    }
}
```

The observers (`Downloader` here) use this method like this:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    System.out.println("Updated downloader");

    if (o instanceof ImageList) {
        ImageList list = (ImageList) o;
        downloadNewImages(list);
    }
}

private synchronized void downloadNewImages(ImageList list) {
    int last = list.getCurrentLastIndex();

    for (Image image : list.getImagesFromTo(readImageFrom, last)) {
        // code gets stuck after this line
        if (filter.isOk(image)) {
            // and before this line
            // [here was a line, but it also fails if I remove it]
        }
    }

    // set the index to the new index
    readImageFrom = last + 1;
}
```

However, sometimes the loop gets stuck and a second call seems to be allowed on the method. Then this is what happens:

- Downloader retrieves images 70 to 70
- Downloader retrieves images 70 to 71
- Downloader retrieves images 70 to 72
- …
- Downloader retrieves images 70 to n

So a second call to the method is allowed entering the method, but the counter `readImageFrom` never gets updated.

When I remove both calls to the other functions within the loop, the script begins to work. I know they are not synchronized, but do they have to be if already the "parent" is synchronized?

`filter.isOK()` is implemented like this (the other functions just return true or false; the code fails when I have `hasRightColor` included, I guess because it is a bit slower to calculate):

```
public boolean isOk(Image image) {
    return hasRightDimensions(image) && hasRightColor(image);
}
```

How can this happen? Eclipse does not show any thrown exception (which of course would cause the method to be exited).

Maybe there also is a totally different approach for getting only the newest content of a list from multiple observers (where each observer might be **notified several times** because the program runs parallel)?

Comment: Which class contains the `downloadNewImages` method? How many instances of this class are there? Where is readImageFrom declared?

Comment: `downloadNewImages` is contained in the `Downloader` (one of the two observers). There is only one instance of `Downloader` (and one instance of the other observer `ImagesWindow`). `readImageFrom` is declared one time in each observer (meaning `Downloader` has one `readImageFrom` and `ImagesWindow` has one `readImageFrom`; each tells how many elements this observer has already seen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the error was some wicked **NullPointerException** which was not displayed to me (whoever knows why) in `filter.isOk()`.

I was not able to see it in my IDE, because I had changed from `this.image` to parameter-passing `image`, but forgot to remove `private image` in the header and to change the parameters of the last of the three functions.

So eclipse did neither say anything about a missing `image` nor about an unused `this.image`.

Finally.