# Fetch only newest elements via observers from a threaded used list

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

This question is related to a problem I am having with [my current implemention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483181/call-to-function-gets-stuck-but-monitor-seems-to-get-freed-how). Thus I am wondering if there might even be a way to implement it totally different.

I am having a `java.util.concurrent` **list** which gets updated by multiple thread. The **list** itself implements `Observable` and then I have two other `Observers` who get informed when the list is changed.

Now the `Observers` shall only load the **newest values** (they do not already have) and not all the thousands the list might contain.

The current overview is like this:

```
public class Observer1 implements Observable {
}

public class Observer2 implements Observable {
}

public class MyList<T> extends Observable {
    private SomeJavaConcurrentList list; // (which one depends on your answer)

    public synchronized void addElement(T element) {
        list.put(element); // or list.add(element); depending on list above
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        MyList list = MyList.getInstance();
        list.add("new element from thread " + this.getName());
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that each observer only gets the entries **it** has not seen, yet?

Possible problems:

- Can I remove the synchronized above somehow? It might slow down the program, when all notification processes need to be awaited? But then `notifyObservers()` might be called multiple times.
- I cannot sure if the observers all have the same state when they are called. One might say: "Oh, I do not update myself now, but next turn I update everything. return" and the other downloads the changes immediately. Thus they have different files.
- there are multiple observers, so I cannot delete existing elements from the list (like with `LinkedBlockingQueue.take()`)

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:
1. each observer will have a member that hold the index of the last indexed that was loaded to the observer, and in the code that notify the observer you will return the elements that added after the index.
2. if you have large number of observers much more than adding maybe you should use readwritelock instead of synchronize.